# await is a reserved word in typescript reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wants to use async await. But it is giving **await is a reserved word**  error. My Code is:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    this.drags();
}
private drags = async () => {
       const e = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container);
    if (e) {
      e.addEventListener("mousedown", (event: any) => {
        await this.dragElement.classList.add("draggable");
        await this.resizeElement.classList.add("resizable");
       }
    }
```

Comment: [`await` is a keyword in plain JavaScript when inside `async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description). I'm not savvy with typescript though.

Comment: resolved. Solution is replace 
this e.addEventListener("mousedown", (event: any) => {
by 
e.addEventListener("mousedown", async (event: any) => {

Comment: `await` must only be used inside the `async` functions. Your `mousedown` handler is not `async`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to start a question with a cut-down, but fully working example of the problem. So here is the starting point, including the error.

declare var ReactDOM: any;

```
class Example {
    dragElement: any;
    resizeElement: any;
    container: any;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.drags();
    }

    private drags = async () => {
        const e = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container);
        if (e) {
            e.addEventListener("mousedown", (event: any) => {
                await this.dragElement.classList.add("draggable");
                await this.resizeElement.classList.add("resizable");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler actually identifies this error with the following message:

> 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

And this points directly to the problem: the function isn't async, so you can't use the `async` keyword.

## Async

Solution One - make it async.

```
declare var ReactDOM: any;

class Example {
    dragElement: any;
    resizeElement: any;
    container: any;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.drags();
    }

    private drags = async () => {
        const e = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container);
        if (e) {
            e.addEventListener("mousedown", async (event: any) => {
                await this.dragElement.classList.add("draggable");
                await this.resizeElement.classList.add("resizable");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## Promise

Solution two - use the promises... I have included this because you can compare the async syntax to the promise syntax.

```
declare var ReactDOM: any;

class Example {
    dragElement: any;
    resizeElement: any;
    container: any;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.drags();
    }

    private drags = async () => {
        const e = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.container);
        if (e) {
            e.addEventListener("mousedown", (event: any) => {
                Promise.all([
                    this.dragElement.classList.add("draggable"),
                    this.resizeElement.classList.add("resizable")
                ])
                    .then((result) => { /* Anything you need to do after */ })
                    .catch((reason) => { throw reason });
            });
        }
    }
}
```